# Getting error in integrating jmeter with spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am trying to integrate jmeter with spring mvc. I have captured all the request using blazemeter and  converted in .jmx file. I have placed this jmx file in test/jmeter folder. When I try to install, I am getting following error.

Executing test: Dagwidouthtml.jmx INFO    2016-07-06 14:10:59.229 [jmeter.e] (): Listeners will be started after enabling running version INFO    2016-07-06 14:10:59.230 [jmeter.e] (): To revert to the earlier behaviour, define jmeterengine.startlistenerslater=false [info] Completed Test: Dagwidouthtml.jmx [info]   [info] Building JMeter Report(s)... [info]   [info] Raw results: /home/trina/git/framework_loadTest/target/jmeter/report/Dagwidouthtml-160706.jtl [info] Test report: /home/trina/git/framework_loadTest/target/jmeter/report/Dagwidouthtml-160706.jtl-report.html [INFO]   [INFO] Test Results: [INFO]   [INFO] Tests Run: 1, Failures: 6, Errors: 0 [INFO]   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 46.269 s [INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-06T14:11:10-04:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 44M/481M [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:1.4.1:jmeter (jmeter-tests) on project framework: There were test failures.  See the jmeter logs for details. -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Answer (score 0):

So why you're posting Maven output here while it states the following:

> There were test failures. **See the jmeter logs for details**

The log file is usually located at `target/jmeter/logs/${yourscript}.log`

Inspect the log file and if you won't be able to figure out the problem yourself.

The possible reason (apart from misconfiguration) I can think of is that [jmeter-maven-plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lazerycode.jmeter/jmeter-maven-plugin/1.10.1) still depends on **JMeter 2.13** so if you're trying to use features, introduced in [JMeter 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-key-things-you-need-know-about-jmeter-30) in your script - the failures are absolutely expected.

Also see documentation on [JMeter Maven Plugin on Github](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) - it is the most comprehensive source.